# YES/No option no visible in Edit Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, site-column

I have this column that I have created and and I wanted to change its type from multiple choice to an Yes/No  option.

Unfortunately I don't see the option anymore.

[image: cl]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**.

It is not possible to change the field type of existing choice column to Yes/No(check box) in SharePoint.

You can change choice column to only below column types:

1. Single line of text
2. Multiple lines of text
3. Choice (menu to choose from)
4. Number (1, 1.0, 100)
5. Currency ($, ¥, €)
6. Date and Time

**EDIT**:

You can change Yes/No column to below column types:

1. Single line of text
2. Multiple lines of text
3. Choice (menu to choose from)
4. Number (1, 1.0, 100)
5. Currency ($, ¥, €)
6. Yes/No (check box)

**For Indexed Error**:

If you want remove the indexing on Yes/No column, then follow below steps:

1. Go to List settings.
2. Scroll down to "Columns" section. After all columns, you can see an option **Indexed columns**. Select it.
3. You can see the list of all indexed columns here. Locate your Yes/No field in this list and click on it.
4. To delete this indexing, click on `Delete`.
5. Then again try to change the type Yes/No column.

**Note**:

1. Before deleting indexed column, make sure deleting it will not affect your list view when list crosses list view threshold.

Comment: This site column used to be yes/no and then I tired to change it to choice option. Unofrtunately I get this error ''The type of this column cannot be changed because it is currently being indexed.'' i dont know what to do .

Comment: see updated answer. How many items are there in your list?

Comment: My Document library has around 11000 items on it ans a list can show me around 5000 items.  All of those files used that column type so I dont really want to delete it

Comment: I am afraid, but you cannot change the field type from Yes/No to choice column if it is indexed.

Comment: What would have to all my items that used that coulumn type and I delete it ?

Comment: Nothing will happen to the items. But if any list view will return more than 5000 items then you cannot see anything in your view.

Comment: Do you have any filters in list view on this column? If No, maybe you can index another columns which are being used frequently for items and add filters on those columns. And then delete this Yes?No column.

Comment: One last thing. So all the items have that column type. If I remove it, it wont be visible ?  Let's say I create a new cloumn type. How do I give or set this coulmn type to all the items. I can't do it manually to all of them.

Comment: The items will be visible if the list view does not cross the threshold. Do not remove the column. Remove the indexing to the column only. Or you will loose all data set in that field.

Comment: What does actually happen to the column if I remove the indexing to that column ? How do I give or set this coulmn type to all the items. I can't do it manually to all of them.

Comment: Nothing will happen to column if you remove indexing. But if you have filters in list view on this column then views will broke. Why do you want to change the type of Yes/No column?

Comment: I wanted to keep this specific column to YES/No but when I go to the setting I dont see any option where I can make this column  required to be filled or changed when file is uploaded. I dont see the option ''Require that this column contains information: '' anywhere. On the other hand if it a Choice Coulmn type I get the option to ''Require that this column contains information: ''

Comment: Yes, you can not make Yes/No column as required/optional field from settings. Maybe you can first create a choice column and write a script to update that choice column with the value of Yes/No field and then delete Yes/no field.

Comment: Im quite new using SharePoint so not really familiar with scripts but still thank you. Maybe create a new column and from new make the users use it but not sure if my consultant would like this

Comment: welcome. please upvote and accpet the answer If it helped you in any way.